# How do you setup CloudFront in P&T S3 plugin & how do you know if it works?

Tags: assets, plugins, s3

I have the P&T Amazon S3 plugin.   It's connected to my S3 bucket.  It stores a few test .PDF files.   It is working.  I am able to access the files - and the URL is that of my S3 bucket - i.e., `my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.pdf`

I created a CloudFront distribution.   It is deployed and enabled.

I added my CloudFront `Distribution ID` to the `CloudFront Distribution ID` field in the plugin.   **Do I need to add the distribution's Domain Name to any of the plugin's settings?**

**How do I know if the image is being accessed through CloudFront?**  The URL has not changed - i.e., - i.e., `my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.pdf`

I can access the .PDFs in my S3 bucket using the CloudFront domain name -- i.e., `cloud-front-domain-name.cloudfront.net/filename.pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up an article that might be helpful for future-people looking for step by step instructions on setting this up: [Setting Up AWS S3 Buckets + CloudFront CDN for your Assets](https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-aws-s3-buckets-cloudfront-distribution-with-craft-cms)

Answer (score 1):

Okay -- this was easy -- I was taking the instructions too literally.  You have to replace the S3 URL with the CloudFront URL.